# Taxonomy Field(s)

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 6, is there an easy way to add fields to taxonomy terms where I can use them as flags in Views? Like a 'Hidden' field on a term, so that it is filtered out of a view presentation?

Answer (score 3):

There is a module for Drupal 6 called [Term Fields](http://drupal.org/project/term_fields):

> Term Fields allows you to define fields for taxonomy terms in the same
>   way that CCK allows you to define fields for nodes.

The project page also claims views integration.  I have only done initial testing with this, but it looks promising and is still being actively worked on.

Answer (score 1):

No, no easy way in drupal 6 from what I've found, unfortunately. You need to write your own module, add the checkbox to the term edit page and expose your custom data to views :/